# Replacing all non-numeric characters in certain columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

How can I remove all non-numeric characters from all columns expect "a"?

**Simulated data**

```
library(tidyverse)

d = tibble(a = c("Tom", "Mary", "Ben", "Jane", "Lucas", "Mark"),
           b = c("8P", "3", "6", "7", "5M", "U1"),
           c = c("2", "12", "6F", "7F", "Y1", "9I"))

d
```

[image]

**Expected output should look as follows**

[image]

Tidyverse solutions are especially appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `across` (within `mutate`) to do it over all columns but `a` and use `regex` (within `str_extract`) to extract only numerics (and convert to numerics type).

```r
library(tidyverse)

d |> 
  mutate(across(-a, ~ . |> str_extract("\\d+") |> as.numeric()))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  a         b     c
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Tom       8     2
2 Mary      3    12
3 Ben       6     6
4 Jane      7     7
5 Lucas     5     1
6 Mark      1     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `parse_number`:

```
d %>%
  mutate(across(c("b", "c"), readr::parse_number))

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# a         b     c
# <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Tom       8     2
# 2 Mary      3    12
# 3 Ben       6     6
# 4 Jane      7     7
# 5 Lucas     5     1
# 6 Mark      1     9
```