# Remove all non-number characters from every cell in a df

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a lot of files where each cell contains a string of letters and special characters, then a number. I would like to remove all non-number characters from every cell in R.

I've looked into solutions using `gsub` and `lapply` but they seem to need you to specify the string to remove. That is a problem as each letter/special character string in each cell is unique. I also tried following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993473/replacing-all-non-numeric-characters-in-certain-columns-in-r), but it removed all charecters completely (I'm guessing that it is not recognizing the numbers as numeric...).

Here is an example of my `df` (just one row):

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dfd:13 | hhh:34 | dsd:15 | ffd:67 | hdf:89 | hhj:43 |

I would like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 34 | 15 | 67 | 89 | 43 |

Comment: It's not at all obvious why the solutions to the previous question aren't working.  Could you please post the results of `dput(head(df))` ... ??

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag and in particular input should be shown in an easily reproducible form using `dput`.  I have done it for you this time in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you G. Grothendieck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ readr::parse_number(.x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you specifically mentioned `lapply` and `gsub` in your question, in base R you can do:

```
df[] <- lapply(df[], function(x) as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x)))
```

Note the `[]` are important here in the use of `lapply` (indicates it should run across all columns). `\\D` indicates everything but a digit, so if there is a negative number it will remove the "-" as well, in which case you may want to extract everything after the colon:

```
df[] <- lapply(df[], function(x) as.numeric(sub(".*\\:", "", x)))
```

Either way, the output is:

```
#   Column_A Column_B Column_C Column_D Column_E Column_F
# 1       13       34       15       67       89       43
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) Base R** We trim off all non-numeric characters (`\\D` means non-numeric) and then converts what is left to numeric using `type.convert`. No packages are used and DF is not overwritten -- overwriting objects is error-prone.  (The input is shown in reproducible form in the Note at the end.)

```
DF |> 
  list(x = _) |>
  with(replace(x, TRUE, lapply(x, trimws, whitespace = "\\D"))) |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
##   Column A Column B Column C Column D Column E Column F
## 1       13       34       15       67       89       43
```

**2) collapse::dapply**  Using the collapse package we can use `dapply` to apply `trimws` over the columns and then as above use type.convert.

```
library(collapse)

DF |>
  dapply(trimws, whitespace = "\\D", drop = FALSE) |> 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
##   Column A Column B Column C Column D Column E Column F
## 1       13       34       15       67       89       43
```

**3) purrr** We can use `map` below.  (`map_dfr` would also work but it was recently deprecated.)

```
library(purrr)

DF %>%
  map(trimws, whitespace = "\\D") %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
##   Column A Column B Column C Column D Column E Column F
## 1       13       34       15       67       89       43
```

**4) furrr**  We can use `map_dfr` from purrr or the corresponding function from furrr.  We show the latter below.  `map_dfr` has been  superseded in purrr although it remains there and is not deprecated.

```
library(furrr)

DF |>
  future_map_dfr(trimws, whitespace = "\\D") |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
## # A tibble: 1 × 6
##   `Column A` `Column B` `Column C` `Column D` `Column E` `Column F`
##        <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
## 1         13         34         15         67         89         43
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(`Column A` = "dfd:13", `Column B` = "hhh:34", 
    `Column C` = "dsd:15", `Column D` = "ffd:67", `Column E` = "hdf:89", 
    `Column F` = "hhj:43"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```